# Secondary display showing Ubuntu logo, but is not detected

Tags: nvidia, display, vga

I recently installed Ubuntu using WUBI, and it worked perfectly. However, my laptop is showing the main desktop screen, and my secondary display is only showing the Ubuntu logo with its loading bar underneath, nothing more. When I go to 'displays' it is only detecting my laptop screen, and not my Asus monitor (connected with a vga).

Things I've done so far: 
Unplug and replug vga cable. 
Reboot computer. 
Re-install Ubuntu. 
Checked to see if any drivers needed to be installed. None were needed.

I have a Thinkpad W520, with a Nvidia Quadro 1000M

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The W520 comes with "nvidia optimus" who's features have limited support in linux so far. When booting, linux will disable the integrated Intel graphics and use your nvidia quadro 1000M. It is however, the integrated intel graphics that runs your VGA-port.

You could try setting your BIOS settings to only use the integrated intel graphics, this would however mean that you won't be able to play heavy games and the like.

> Press F12 when starting your computer during the "THINKPAD" splash screen. Set the 
>   display setting to "Integrated".

If this causes you any trouble, you can easily go back to BIOS and revert to your previous settings.

More information can be found at http://zachstechnotes.blogspot.se/2012/01/tri-head-display-on-linux-thinkpad-w520.html